# app visibility in app store for apple watch

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, apple-watch

I'm developing a xamarin forms app and my client wants to check if it will be
shown in the appstore in apple watch.
He wants it to be available only for phones and not be visible for watches and iPads.

In the plist file, I selected iPhone/iPod in the Devices selection.
My question is, will that be enough to hide it in the app store for watches and iPads?
Or are there other things that I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All iPhone apps are available for iPads. If you don't select iPad as a target device in Xcode then the app will run in a scaled mode on iPads. You can't opt out of this. The app will only appear in the App Store on watch if it includes a watch app or is a stand-alone watch app.

Comment: You can try specifying `nfc` or `telephony` in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to exclude iPad,  but generally it is a bad idea to arbitrarily exclude a device family.

Answer (score 0):

The app won't be available on the Watch if you don't have a Watch extension in your project.